# How to test reducer with Immer/produce?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

How can I write unit test (Jest) for reducer that using immer's produce function?
Using produce does not return a state - the state is "mutable".
How can Jest test this code and have coverage of the switch/case branches?

sample reducer:

```
const appReducer = produce((state: IAppState, action: IAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_APP_REQ:
      break;
    case FETCH_APP_SUCCESS:
      state.appDetails = action.payload;
      break;
    case FETCH_APPLICATION_FAILURE:
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}, initialState);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example is the following testing the action `FETCH_APP_SUCCESS`

```
 describe("app-reducer", () => {
  describe("FETCH_APP_SUCCESS", () => {
    it("should set the appDetails", () => {
      const storeState = reducer(initialState, {
        type: "FETCH_APP_SUCCESS",
        payload: { appDetails: "appDetails" },
      });
      const newState = produce(initialState, (draftState) => {
        initialState.appDetails = "appDetails";
      });
      expect(storeState).toEqual(newState);
    });
  });
```